# Get text from element immediately following an element with specific text

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape job postings and I'm having Selenium go to each individual posting to get some text.  The problem is the structure of the page isn't the same for every posting so I'm trying to tell Selenium to grab the text from the element that immediately follows a div that contains the text Job Scope since that is where the text always is.

Here is one site, again it's not the same for every one but is always after Job Scope/Duties: https://recruitingbypaycor.com/career/JobIntroduction.action?clientId=8a87142e46c6fe710146f995773e6461&id=8a78839e812f7de70181456c3ad709ff&source=&lang=en

Here is my code:

```
job_descriptions = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID,"gnewtonJobDescriptionText")))
    for job in job_descriptions:
        job_description.append(job.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Job Scope')]/following-sibling::div"))
```

I've got the script to work here but it produces empty list.  So when I add .text to the end it errors our saying 'list' object has no attribute 'text' (obviously since it's producing an empty list.  The only thing I can think of is that the text Job Scope is actually within a b tag inside the preceding div so maybe that's why?

Comment: Can you confirm the url for the page with job postings list?

Comment: The url is: https://www.starone.org/careers/

Comment: However, I've got a for loop to grab the actual links and go to them:

hrefs=[]
for link in links[:10]:
    hrefs.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
    titles.append(link.text)

for href in hrefs:
    browser.get(href)
    job_descriptions = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID,"gnewtonJobDescriptionText")))
    for job in job_descriptions:
        job_description.append(job.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Job Scope')]/following-sibling::div"))

Comment: That page has a div with `id="indeed-apply-iframe-holder"`. You may want to look up those jobs on indeed, they have better structure: https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=paycor&l=

Comment: Thanks! I was basically practicing using Selenium and for loops to access a list of urls but then I got stuck on this.